# How to update config in HighChart with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to change options of HighChart by useState.
Then I could use a button click to re-render the chart.

Here is my code:

```
const options = {
  title: {
    text: "My chart",
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 1, 0],
    },
    {
      data: [1, 2, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 0],
    },
  ],
};

export default function HighChartContainer() {
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(options);

  const handleChangeOptions = () => {
    const newLineData = [
      {
        data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 7, 0],
      },
      {
        data: [1, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 0],
      },
    ];
    const newOptions = { ...chartOptions, series: newLineData };
    setChartOptions(newOptions);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ChartWrapper>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={chartOptions}
        />
      </ChartWrapper>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleChangeOptions}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It didn't work. I tried google but couldn't find anyone who wrote code in this pattern.
Is there anything wrong?

My code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-framework-jjoh4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `handleChangeOptions` from the callback to see the effect. Additionally it is enough to update the chart with only new options:

```
const handleChangeOptions = () => {
  const newLineData = [
    {
      data: [...]
    },
    {
      data: [...]
    }
  ];
  const newOptions = { series: newLineData };
  setChartOptions(newOptions);
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-johnson-gpv99?file=/src/App.js

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

Comment: You also remove object spread operator in my function.

const newOptions = { ...chartOptions, series: newLineData };
I have to remove it as well then it could work. Why is that?

Comment: Hi @Doraemon, As I mentioned - it is enough to update the chart with only new options. You don't need to keep all current options in a state.

Answer (score 0):

After you update question. I saw the problem is you pass `callback={handleChangeOptions}` in `HighchartsReact`. So you just remove it. everything will work normally.

Comment: Oh sorry I mistype it. But it won't re-render even if I use chartOptions from useState. I will append a code sandbox later.